# How to read appsettings.json in my _layout.chtml

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, configuration, appsettings

I cannot seem to figure out how to read values from the appsettings.json in my _Layout.chtml file.

Is it not just available, something like this?
@Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]

I created a new MVC project using razor pages.

fyi, i'm an mvc newbee - code samples help a lot.

Answer (score 133):

In .net core mvc you can inject the configuration by adding the following two lines at the top of your view:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
```

You can then access the value like this:

```
@Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights")["InstrumentationKey"]
```

Comment: It's also possible to use the shorthand `@Configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"]` to access the values.

Comment: This syntax is not working in Blazor SPA .razor pages.  Does anybody know how to?

Comment: Maybe ```@Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").GetValue<string>("InstrumentationKey")``` for you @Nathan

Answer (score 6):

If you use the options pattern you can inject them into your view like this:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@inject IOptions<ApplicationInsightsOptions> 
ApplicationInsightsOptionsAccessor
@
{
   var instrumentationKey = 
        ApplicationInsightsOptionsAccessor.Value.InstrumentationKey;
}
```

[Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Answer (score 3):

Using `ActionFilters` you can interrupt the request and add the configuration variables maybe to the `ViewBag` so it becomes accessible from the views or from the `_Layout.cshtml` File.

For example, if the following configuration section is inside your `appsettings.json`

```
{
    "MyConfig": {
        "MyValue": "abc-def"
    }
}
```

In the code `MyConfig.cs` would be:

```
public class MyConfig
{
    public string MyValue{ get; set; }
}
```

First create a very simple ActionFilter which derives from `IAsyncActionFilter` as following :

```
public class SampleActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private MyConfig _options;
    public SampleActionFilter(IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        _options = new MyConfig();
        configuration.Bind(_options);
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller)context.Controller).ViewBag.MyConfig = _options;
        await next();
    }
}
```

Later in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method change `services.AddMvc` to the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    //..........

    services.AddMvc(options=>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new SampleActionFilter(
            Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig")
        ));
    });

    //..........

}
```

To access the values just simply in the `_Layout.cshtml` or other view you can type:

```
@ViewBag.MyConfig.MyValue
```