# New Area is Razor Pages is not displaying the root _Layout.cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm working on a new Razor Page app for asp.net core.

Issue: I've added a new Area folder (TeamDrawing), but a reference to the Root/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml page is not working when I place the _ViewStart.cshtml with in the Area/TeamDrawing/Pages folder or Area/TeamDrawing folder.

I am using asp.net identity (built-in with the template I used) within the Area/Identity folder and it references the Root/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml without issues.

What am I doing wrong?

I want to use my Root/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml in all of my Area folders.

Here is my Area folder:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Here is the root Pages Folder:

[image: ![enter image description here]

**UPDATE:**

My issue appears to be something else. I didn't realize I had an F12 console error. The Root/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml calls some code to load my menu items and the path is trying to go to a controller within Area/TeamDrawing instead of the Controller on the root. I need to figure out how to point back to the root/Controller.

So the pointing to the _Layout in the root seems to be fine.

**UPDATE 2:**

If I put the direct URL within the `get` call it will work.

Is there a way I can not put the direct URL within the URL

Works:

```
    $.get(BuildSafeURL("https://localhost:44355/ToolbarMenu/LoadToolbarMenuItems", null))
        .done(function (data) {

        });
```

Breaks because it tries to go to the controller within Area/TeamDrawing:

```
  $.get(BuildSafeURL("ToolbarMenu/LoadToolbarMenuItems", null))
        .done(function (data) {
        
        });
```

I've tried this in my Root/_Layout file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Global variable for relative pathing for ajax calls
        var rootPath = '@Url.Content("~")';
    </script>
```

But this doesn't work with `rootPath`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go to the controller within Area/TeamDrawing,try to use:

```
$.get(BuildSafeURL("/ToolbarMenu/LoadToolbarMenuItems", null))
        .done(function (data) {
        
        });
```

Comment: that didn't work :/ I'm still testing, but looking at this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63067506

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now:

Full Code:

Root _Layout.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
    <script>      
         const rootPath = @Json.Serialize(@Configuration.GetSection("ApiUrls").GetSection("commonUrl").Value + "/")
    </script>
```

appsetting.js

```
{
  "ApiUrls": {
    "commonUrl": "https://localhost:44355"
  }
}
```

app.js -> BuildSafeUrl() (used when calling the `get` to the controller to get the menu items)

```
function BuildSafeURL(serverPath, parameterCollection) {

    // Validate the serverPath is well formed
    serverPath = ValidateServerPath(serverPath);

    // Append the rootPath to handle virtual directory pathing
    var path = rootPath + serverPath;

    // Encode and append any search parameters
    if (parameterCollection && parameterCollection.length > 0) {
        path += "?";

        var searchParameters = new URLSearchParams();

        for (var i = 0; i < parameterCollection.length; i++) {

            var key = parameterCollection[i].Key;
            var value = parameterCollection[i].Value;

            searchParameters.append(key, encodeURIComponent(value));
        }

        path += searchParameters.toString();
    }
    return path;
}

function ValidateServerPath(serverPath) {
    if (!serverPath) {
        return '';
    }
    else if (serverPath === '/') {
        return '';
    }
    else if (serverPath.charAt(0) === '/') {
        return serverPath.substring(1);
    }
    else {
        return serverPath;
    }
}
```

toolbarMenu.js -> Where I was within the Area/TeamDrawing folder and calling the controller on the root (outside of the Area folder)

```
function loadToolbarMenuList() {
    $.get(BuildSafeURL("ToolbarMenu/LoadToolbarMenuItems", null))
        .done(function (data) {
          
        })
        .fail(error =>
        {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

Now my Menu items are displaying properly on Area/TeamDrawing/Pages/GenerateChristmasList

[image]