# How do you read from appsettings.json in the same style as it's predecessor, webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, configuration, razor-pages

In `WebForms` we would have a `web.config` file that we could do `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"];` to retrieve the value from the key-value pair.

I've just started a project in `.NET 5.0` and there doesn't seem a simple way to do something that seems to trivial?

I've looked online and have been unsuccessful in following tutorials on how to access these keys in `appsettings.json` from a `.cshtml` file using `@` notation.

**appsettings.json**:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MyKey": "wwwwwwwwwww"
}
```

**Index.cshtml**:

```
<h1>
    Title - @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyKey"];
</h1>
```

The above illustrates what I am trying to achieve, is there a simple way to do this rather than creating classes etc as I don't seem to be able to follow their examples.

Comment: Can you link the tutorials you are talking about?  Have you also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48979294/how-to-read-appsettings-json-in-my-layout-chtml)?

Comment: None of that makes sense/works. What is ApplicationInsights, I put those using/inject at the top of the .cshtml and did this `@Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights")["MyKey"];` and that's empty (displays nothing on the page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[To access configuration settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#access-configuration-in-razor-pages) in a view in a .NET project, you should be able to use `@` annotation.  This is done by injecting the configuration into the page:

```
@page
@model Test5Model
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

Configuration value for 'MyKey': @Configuration["MyKey"]
```

Take this appsettings.json for example:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Test": "Hello World",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SomeContext": "SomeConnectionStringProperties"
  },
  "SectionOne": {
    "SectionOneTestVal": "SomeTestValue"
  }
}
```

In order to access the `Test` key, it would simply be `@Configuration["Test"]` while to access the `SectionOneTestVal` "key" in the `SectionOne` section, you would do something like `Configuration.GetSection("SectionOne")["SectionOneTestVal"]`:

Thus adding this to a view:

```
<p>@Configuration["Test"]</p>
<p>@Configuration.GetSection("SectionOne")["SectionOneTestVal"]</p>
```

...would yield:

[image: Result]

For more information and examples, also check out [dependency injection into views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configuration-injection).